# Stacks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack

I am working with stacks on the infamous 'Braces' problem and I got to a halt. This should be an easy fix but my eyes are not much of a help at the moment.

The first call to the function is working like a charm but the second one is running an extra time and I can't see why.

The first call returns 01110 which is correct but the second returns 011110 which is not...

If you can't read the code here, got to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crematorio/Pe53Q/)

```
//constructor function for our Stack class
function Stack() {
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.top = 0;
    this.push = push;
    this.pop = pop;
    this.peek = peek;
    this.length = length;
    this.clear = clear;
}

function push(element) {
    this.dataStore[this.top++] = element;
}

function pop() {
    return this.dataStore[--this.top];
}

function peek() {
    return this.dataStore[this.top - 1];
}

function length() {
    return this.top;
}

function clear() {
    this.top = 0;
}


function braces(expression) {

    for (var i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
        //if the number of elements in the expression is odd, it is guaranteed not to have a matching expression
        //therefore we print 0
        if (expression[i].length%2 !== 0) {
            console.log(0);
        } else {
            var s = new Stack();
            var startPoint = expression[i].charAt(0);

            //if the expression starts with an open brace it means we will not have a matching expression so we print 0
            if (startPoint == '(' || startPoint == '{' || startPoint == '[') {
                for (var j = 0; j < expression[i].length; j++) {
                    var char = expression[i].charAt(j);
                    var h = '';
                    if (char == '(' || char == '{' || char == '[') {
                        s.push(char);
                    } else {
                        h = s.peek();
                        if (h == "(" && char == ")") {
                            s.pop();
                        } else if (h == "{" && char == "}") {
                            s.pop();
                        } else if (h == "[" && char == "]") {
                            s.pop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log(0);
            }

            if (s.length() == 0) {
                console.log(1)
            } else {
                console.log(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

var expr = [ "}()()", "[]({})", "([])", "{()[]}", "([)]" ]; //working
var expr2 = [ "}()(){", "[]({})", "([])", "{()[]}", "([)]" ]; //running an extra time

braces(expr);
```

Comment: Not so infamous, I'm having trouble looking up what the "braces problem" is in the first place. Is it just trying to parse through braces?

Comment: Checking if the expression has matching braces. If it does I return 1 if not I return 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
        else {
            console.log(0);
            continue; //this is new
        }

        if (s.length() == 0) {
```

Your function would log both 0 and 1/0 if the startpoint is not `{` or `(` or `[` and the length of s was 0

Comment: @Geo  seemed fun to make this, made my own: http://jsfiddle.net/Pe53Q/1/ . Feel free to check it out

Comment: Very interesting approach Juvian :)

Answer (score 1):

Your stack functions are all outside of the scope of `Stack()` and therefore the data probably won't be what you expect. You can start fixing this by putting functions inside the Stack() function:

```
function Stack() {
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.top = 0;
    this.push = push;
    this.pop = pop;
    this.peek = peek;
    this.length = length;
    this.clear = clear;

    this.pop = function () {
        // pop
    }

    this.push = function () {
        // code
    }

    this.peek = function () {
        // code
    }

}
```

That way, the methods all have access to the same data.

Comment: But I am calling the `Stack()` from inside the `braces()` right after the first `else`

Comment: But the `Stack` object doesn't have any relation to `push()`, `pop()`, `peek()`, `length()`, and `clear()` functions. So you'll need to nest those functions inside the `Stack` object in order to use them properly.

Comment: @LaughDonor I made the changes but I have the same issue. If that was the issue, would't it be affecting my first expression and not only the second one?